# TSQL Optimization - WHERE clause without LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, optimization, where-clause

What is the most optimized solution for this situation:

WHERE clause of my query is like this:

```
WHERE columnX LIKE @Account + '%'
```

I use '%' because @Account could be ' ' and in that case I want to get all values. In all other cases I could use equals (=).

This solution is not optimized because I have index on columnX and I would like to use equals (=) because of that.  Also, solution with OR is not acceptable because of performance.

Do you have some other recommendation? I tried with CASE in WHERE clause, but didn't find good solution that is optimized. Our compatibility level is 80, so cannot use newer syntax. (don't ask why :-) )

TnX in advance!

Nemanja

Comment: Why can't you split it into two sections(queries) by an if (@Account ='') statement? So if @Account='' you don't need WHERE clause at all.

Comment: That was one of solutions, but it looks like code redundancy and performance are not so good. Also, because this code is in procedure, I would need to add WITH RECOMPILE because of different EXECUTION PLANS in two different cases.

Comment: In the code where you construct the query, test if Account is blank or null, and then redirect to run a query which says get all rows.  Otherwise, use  where columnX = Account.

Comment: @Eric Do you mean to use IF clause or some other way?

Comment: You would have to post your entire function or procedure for step by step instructions on what to type.

Comment: SQL Server can use a range seek for the query `WHERE columnX LIKE @Account + '%'` anyway [as shown here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/01/18/dynamic-seeks-and-hidden-implicit-conversions.aspx). If it doesn't that presumably means the index on `columnX` doesn't cover the query in which case you need two separate plans for both cases anyway as the choice is between seek and lookups vs a scan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this

```
where columnX = isnull(nullif(@Account, ''), columnX)
```

Comment: Even this solution didn't improve performance of my query, this syntax is very interesting and useful!

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to execute two semantically different queries; one to pull all rows, and one to pull a single row.  These two queries will by definition have two different query plans.  Your attempt to combine them into one query to avoid "code duplication" is misguided.  "Code duplication" is *not* the enemy, complexity is.  The answer is for you to create a stored proc for each scenario.  This will not only allow each stored proc to represent a single query plan;  you will also simplify your application by following the [single responsibility principle](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/The_Single_Responsibility_Principle).

Comment: Thank you for answer about code duplication and SRP. Because of specific situation, I'm not able to create two procedures, but I will leave IF ELSE in procedure and add WITH RECOMPILE to avoid problems with EXECUTION PLAN.

Answer (score 0):

this is a situation we all face :)

There is nothing much you can do really if you what a select with a Like. Your situation is not the worst, if you only add the % in the end, there is a good chance the index will be used for a seek. The real problem is when you have % in the begining where the index, if used, will be on a scan

also, bear in mind that the index usage is also related with the columns you have on your select. If you have a table with ID and Name, with an index on name, and select * from it the index probably wont be used.

To finish, you could consider fulltext search, but it's implementation is rather complicated

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(10) = '' 
DECLARE @table TABLE ( ID VARCHAR(10) ) 

INSERT INTO @table 
SELECT '11' 
UNION 
SELECT '2' 

SELECT * 
FROM @table 
WHERE ( Len(@var) = 0 OR ID = @var ) 

SET @var = '11' 

SELECT * 
FROM @table 
WHERE ( Len(@var) = 0 OR ID = @var )
```

Answer (score 0):

On some versions of SQL server, the OR is not a performance issue if you use `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`. For more information, see http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html